# Why Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo") is disabled in a particular sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot figure out why `Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo")` is disabled in a particular sheet.

I also tried to explicitely enable it with:

```
Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").Enabled = True
```

But still no results:

```
Dim lastAction As String
If Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").Enabled = True Then
MsgBox "It works"
lastAction = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
If Left(lastAction, 5) = "Paste" Then
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Call MasterPageFixer

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Else
Exit Sub
End If
End If
```

Any idea about how to programmatically make sure that this sheet could keep the possibility of accessing the undo list?

Comment: Do you use somebody else workbook? If so, please check what sheet events are in place. Especially, `Activate` \ `Deactivate` events,

Comment: I am using my own workbook. When the workbook opens I placed a code to run: Private Sub Workbook_Open() Sheet16.Activate ...code.... End Sub. In this code there is nothing that refers to disabling and enabling events or the Standard commandbar.

Comment: Then, what does "disabled in a particular sheet" means? Doesn't it work as it should in the other sheets?

Comment: It means that when I do any action in my Master sheet, in particular a paste action, the command bar looks like inactive and no undo action is allowed. So I copy and paste some names and I cannot undo because the undo bar is inactive.

Comment: **Doesn't it work as it should in the other sheets?**

Comment: Yes it does, this is why I cannot see why in this sheet that is not working

Comment: If not something confidential in the workbook, can you share it? I would like to see such a peculiar one and we will maybe find an explanation... Any protection on the sheet in discussion?

Comment: This is a bit of a shot in the dark but I've encountered issue before where a `Worksheet_Change` or `Workbook_SheetChange` event causes people to be unable to undo any inputs. The event script was altering some cells to help autofill common values, but Excel cannot undo a macro output, so Undo was wiped every time the macro ran, which was every time the user entered a value on the sheet. I suspect you might have a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

The `Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").Enabled` refers to the standard arrows for "Undo" in Excel. These are not per sheet, but per application, as the line says. They arrows are enabled/disabled if there is a possibility to use them. Thus, the "disabled" stands only if there is nothing to be "undone". E.g., check the following steps:

1. Open a new Excel workbook and run this in the Immediate window. You will see `False`:

[image: ?Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").Enabled]

2. This is because there is nothing to be "undone":

[image]

3. Then, if you write some text in the excel cells and run the code from the immediate window again, you will see `True`. Additionally, the arrow will look like this:

[image]

Comment: And what if before doing that I just pasted an item and he result is still false?

Comment: @Kurt - can you try writing these two before pasting the item - `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`
`Application.EnableEvents = True`

Comment: it's done, it's in the above code

Comment: @Kurt - try only with those 3 lines in a separate workbook. Make sure that it works. Then investigate further, trying to replicate what has happened to the "sick" workbook with the non-working worksheet.